# What is this Webpack error about because I can't find solution anywhere?

Tags: javascript, webpack

In the terminal I typed out this command: webpack -w

````
 - configuration.module has an unknown property 'loaders'. These properties are valid:
   object { defaultRules?, exprContextCritical?, exprContextRecursive?, exprContextRegExp?, exprContextRequest?, generator?, noParse?, parser?, rules?, strictExportPresence?, strictThisContextOnImports?, unknownContextCritical?, unknownContextRecursive?, unknownContextRegExp?, unknownContextRequest?, unsafeCache?, wrappedContextCritical?, wrappedContextRecursive?, wrappedContextRegExp? }
   -> Options affecting the normal modules (`NormalModuleFactory`).
   Did you mean module.rules or module.rules.*.use?
 - configuration.output.path: The provided value "./dist" is not an absolute path!
   -> The output directory as **absolute path** (required).```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** - you put `loaders` object in a wrong place as error one says

> configuration.module has an unknown property 'loaders'.

If you look at [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#ruleloaders) `loaders` is inside `module.rules` (error also mentions it - module has no such key) but it is also **deprecated**. Instead use `use` like in example below

```
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
  //...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        //...
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

**Second**

> configuration.output.path: The provided value "./dist" is not an absolute path!

This basically mean that you should provide absolute path. To do that include `path` library at the top and define your iutput with `path.resolve()` - more info [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputpath)

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  //...
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
};
```

P.S. It is hard to know for sure will this help you without your `webpack.config.js` so I recommend you to provide its code also next time.